# OverridePendingTransition для активити

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть 2 активити, нужно сделать переход между ними с анимацией. Первая активити уезжает вверх экрана по оси Y, вторая выезжает снизу экрана.

Проблема в том, что при слайдинге виден черный фон, полоса по экрану прямо.
Если переделать анимацию, для оси X никаких черных полос нет.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), REQ_DO_LOGIN);

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_enter, R.anim.activity_exit);
```

R.anim.activity_enter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

R.anim.activity_exit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />
```

Comment: Черная полоса это status bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо это костыль, но проблему решило

R.anim.activity_enter

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="80%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```